# python - importError: no module named pysphere

Tags: python, importerror, python-import

I am able to type the following into python.exe to create a session to Vmware Esxi

```
from pysphere import VIServer
server = VIServer()
server.connect("myserver", "user", "password")
```

When I save the same code into a .py file and execute from Windows command line I get

> ImportError: No module named pysphere.

When I look in Lib\site-packages there is a pysphere folder. I am running the .py from `c:\python\` and my python package is in `c:\python27`

I am not use to seeing the from command and so don't really understand

Comment: How do you call the script? It looks like you have two python installs.

Comment: Do you have `pip` installed?  If so, try `pip freeze`.  Also, can you tell us what you get if you run `python -c "import sys; print sys.executable"` from the command line?

Comment: ok that helped me sr2222 :-)

Answer (score 1):

when I ran that command it showed version 2.6.3 not 2.7. I adjusted the path in environment variables from 2.6 to 2.7. Then found registry key pointing to 2.6 so updated that to 2.7 (python.file - shell - open - command).